# Openshift deployment not resetting completely

Tags: openshift

I have been managing two domains and several applications successfully on Openshift for a while.

One of my applications now refuses to update the landing page "index.jsp" and other pages and functionality.

I have tried restarting the application and cleaning it up with rhc with no success.

Is there a way to force the refresh without deleting and re-deploying?

Comment: Can you describe in more details how exactly you are deploying, include the deploy output, what cartridges are used, etc? For example - Java server cartridges provide [more deployment options](https://developers.openshift.com/servers/tomcat/deployment-options.html); if source files are being pushed, the maven build could be failing thus the result not deployed...

Comment: The server was apaprently not refreshing or clearing the cache or something hence the old files were appearing. I woke up and it had updated the next morning.